# Is it possible to use inner classes to declare endpoints on spring?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm trying to organize better my controllers and I came up with the idea of splitting this huge controller into two separated controllers, the main controller have a lot of methods, example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/queues")
class QueueController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    fun index() = "index"
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    fun store() = "store queue"

    @GetMapping(value = "/{queue}/messages")
    fun findMessagesByQueue(@PathVariable("queue") queue: String) = "messages from $queue"

    @PostMapping(value = "/{queue}/messages")
    fun storeMessage(@PathVariable("queue") queue: String) = "store message"

}
```

What I want is to create two separated controllers, one for `queue` and one for `message`, but in order to achieve this I need to access the path variable "queue" on the `message` controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/queues")
class QueueController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index() = "index"

    // ...
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/queues/{queue}/messages")
class MessageController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index() = "how to access que $queue value?"

    // ...
}
```

I've tried to use a single controller with two `inner classes`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/queues/")
class Controller {

    // map this controller to an endpoint? how?
    inner class Queues {}

    // map this controller to an endpoint? how?
    inner class Messages {}
}
```

- This `inner class` approach does not work, if I try to call `queues` I got a `404`, is it possible to use `inner classes` to organize the controller?
- Is it possible to access the path variable declared on the controller annotation?

Comment: Are you sure the "404" is being raised because of the inner classes? Can you show the code and how did you try to get it from the url?

Answer (score 1):

This is right approach in your case I think (it works on SpringBoot 3.1.2):

```kotlin
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

class ControllerWrapper {
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("inner1")
    class InnerController() {
        @GetMapping("hi")
        fun hello(): String {
            return "hi"
        }
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("inner2")
    class InnerController2() {

        @GetMapping("hi")
        fun hello(): String {
            return "hi"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi echo, on the `InnerController2` how can I get a path variable? Take a look at my question on the 2nd code block.